# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier в function init()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">window.addEventListener('load',function(){
        $(function($){
            $.validator.addMethod("validPhone", function(value, element) {
                return this.optional(element) ||  value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'').length>10;
            }, "Формат номера");
            var Forms = {
                validation: function validation() {
                    var timePost=0;
                    var $form = $('#{form.ID}');
                    $form.validate({
                        submitHandler: function(form) {
                            if(timePost<Date.now())
                            {
                                timePost=Date.now()+1e3;
                                var data={ ajax:1};

                                $('[name]',form).each(function(){ data[this.name] = $(this).val() });

                                $.post( $(form).attr('action') ,data ,function(rT){

                                    if(rT=='OK'){
                                        $('#{form.ID}').closest('.form-text').hide().siblings('.side').show();
                                    }else{
                                        $.each( eval('('+rT+')') ,function( i , v ) {
                                            $('#'+i).rules('error' , v);
                                        })
                                    };
                                });
                            }
                            return!1;
                        }
                    });

                    <!-- BEGIN rules -->
                        {.RULE}
                    <!-- END rules -->

                },


                <!--init: function init() {
                /* init radio, mask and checkbox */
                var $form = $('#{form.ID}');
                $form.find('.dropdown').each(function(){ $(this).closest('field-input').addClass('field-input-mb-select') });
                $form.find(".dropdown").dropdown();
                //$form.find(".phone-mask").mask("+7 (999) 999-99-99");
                $form.find(".form-block").find("input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]").checkbox();

                Forms.validation();
              }
            };
            Forms.init();




    });
})</script>
```

вот в этом куске:

```
<!--init: function init() {
            /* init radio, mask and checkbox */
            var $form = $('#{form.ID}');
            $form.find('.dropdown').each(function(){ $(this).closest('field-input').addClass('field-input-mb-select') });
            $form.find(".dropdown").dropdown();
            //$form.find(".phone-mask").mask("+7 (999) 999-99-99");
            $form.find(".form-block").find("input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]").checkbox();

            Forms.validation();
          }
        };
        Forms.init();
```

а точнее в `var $form = $('#{form.ID}');` вылетает ошибка

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier.

Comment: Ваш код явно должен быть обработан каким то шаблонизатором. Добавьте в вопрос код, который получается после этой операции

Comment: Если нужно просто выбрать элемент с ID `form.ID`, то делается это так: `$('#form\\.ID')`.